# How to solve login failed issue using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I have been searching out to solve this problem on stackoverflow,
then no appropriate answers.
**The issue is like following:**
[image]

What I've tried:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://all-access.wax.io/")
```

Then I tried to add any kind possible arguments to `chrome_options`.
Then still same result.

Comment: what is page_url  ? is it supported on chrome as the message says `the browser or application may be insecure` ?

Comment: @cruisepandey, hi. nice to meet you

Comment: I will write it in code

Comment: Are you able to by pass captcha ?

Comment: yes passed by captcha

Comment: I already made bot to pass captcha, but for now want to login google

Comment: and when you click on login you see that message ?

Comment: after enrolled gmail and clicked next button

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to login to Google using testing software, you need to enable less secure apps to access your account.

You can find the option here:

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: but i can't set security for every user every time

Comment: I see. I didn’t quite understand the way you were using it. I’m sure there’s a solution. I’ll investigate further and see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before, and I've found that the problem is that I was using Chrome. Try switching to Firefox; it solved the problem for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

To use Firefox in Selenium you will need a geckodriver, which can be downloaded here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

More information about `webdriver.Firefox()` here: [selenium firefox](https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-firefox/)

Comment: by the way, i want it with chrome

Comment: @CharlieSchwab Is there some things that you want to use Chrome for that you can't using Firefox? Extensions maybe?